# angular survey dynamic questions rendering template driven or reactive

Tags: angular9, survey, dynamic-forms

I am new at angular currently started a project with angular 9 to build survey application where I have
dynamic questions with
**different question type** (radio,checkbox, textbox, textarea, dropdown,etc)
**question options** (dynamic for each question)
**dynamic attributes** like (required, minlength, maxlength, pattern, data-attributes)

I started with template driven form, but having issues with attribute, multiple checkboxes and may face more issue in future
while reactive Forms looks too much complex
Looking for expert suggesion which method should I follow

currently at teplate driven forms to render checkboxes I wrote this code

```
<!--checkbox type=2 -->
<div class="optgroup" *ngSwitchCase="2">
    <div *ngFor="let opt of question.QuestionOption; let io = index" class="form-check form-check-inline mx-3" >
        <input type="checkbox" 
            name="data[{{survey.Survey.id}}][{{section.id}}][{{question.id}}][]"
            [id]="'rdo'+is+iq+io" 
            value="{{opt.title}}" 
            class="form-check-input"
            ngModel />
        <label [for]="'rdo'+is+iq+io" class="form-check-label">{{opt.title}}</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am able to select multiple checkboxes but at `{{f.value | json}}` only last changed value is coming as boolean but not array of select values.

and secondly how can add attribute dynamically
`if(webservice.currentQuestion.attrubutes != null){
   loop over attributes and 
   add each attribute to let's say above checkbox or <input type="text"> or <select>
}`
have no idea how can add these dynamic attributes